# Covert SQL to django ORM (inner join sub-select)

Tags: sql, django

This is my follow model. Given a user id, I want to get all of the users that given user is following based on an inner join of target_id's

```
class Follow(Activity, BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='following')
    target = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='follower')
```

This is achieved with this raw sql query, given that i am looking for all followings of user.id 1

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT target_id 
       FROM   auth_user 
              INNER JOIN api_follow 
                  ON auth_user.id = api_follow.user_id 
       WHERE  api_follow.user_id = 1) AS targets 
       INNER JOIN auth_user 
           ON targets.target_id = auth_user.id;
```

How can i do this efficiently in djangos orm? I need a User queryset so that i can pass to my UserSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Find all followers of the given user id:

`User.objects.filter(follower__user=id)`

Comment: That returns a queryset of users that are followers of my user, i want to get who my user is following